# Kafka java.lang.IllegalStateException: topics, topicPattern, or topicPartitions must be provided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka and I am currently working on a small Kafka project. I am working on an example involving Spring Boot and Kafka consumer. However, I am getting an IllegalStateException.

I have a Kafka Configuration class:

```
package com.example.springbootwithkafkaconsumer.config;

import com.example.springbootwithkafkaconsumer.model.Customer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@KafkaListener
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Customer> customerConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_json");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Customer.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> customerKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(customerConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and a Consumer class:

```
package com.example.springbootwithkafkaconsumer;

import com.example.springbootwithkafkaconsumer.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;

@Configuration
public class Consumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Kafka_Example", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consumeMessageString(String message) { System.out.println("Consumed String Message: " + message); }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "Kafka_Example_Json", groupId = "group_json",
            containerFactory = "customerKafkaListenerFactory")
    public void consumeMessageJson(Customer customer) { System.out.println("Consumed JSON Message: " + customer); }
}
```

For some reason, the error message says that a topic must be provided, but I already provided two topics in the Consumer class.

Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: topics, topicPattern, or topicPartitions must be provided
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.<init>(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:145) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.<init>(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:81) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:75) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainerInstance(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:46) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:377) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java:69) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:156) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:196) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:186) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.example.springbootwithkafkaconsumer.SpringBootWithKafkaConsumerApplication.main(SpringBootWithKafkaConsumerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:an]
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using the @KafkaListener annotation in the Kafka Configuration class. I replaced it with the @EnableKafka annotation and it fixed the problem.